# Setting event crashing the application

Tags: c#, revit-api

In this below code while setting the Elbow object its crashing the program.
I'm quite new in using events can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here?

```html
 public STag tag { get; set; }
        private event EventHandler ElbowModified;
        public XYZ Start { get; set; }
        public XYZ Elbow { 
            get { return Elbow; } 
            set { Elbow = value;
                ElbowModified.Invoke(0, EventArgs.Empty); } }

 

        public DummyTag(STag sTag)
        {
            try
            {
                ElbowModified += DummyTag_ElbowModified;
                BoundingBoxModified += DummyTag_BoundingBoxModified;

           


                if (sTag.TagObject.HasElbow)
                {
                    this.Elbow = new XYZ(0, 0, 0);
              
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Elbow = new XYZ(0, 0, 0);
                   
                }
```

Comment: Your setter for Elbow refers to itself (Elbow = value). This will cause the setter to be called an infinite number of times (or until you run out of memory). I suspect what you want to do, is to have a private field XYZ elbow. Then have your Elbow property refer to the private field, instead of itself.

Comment: oh, no.
What a silly mistake I have done.
Thanks for pointing out.